# Custom Search in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

## Details

I am trying to implement search in angular 2 but I have no clue how to do it. I already go to different tutorials but they all not fit in my case. I have a table in which user are shown now I want to search user on Name/Email. give me some good ideas how I can do this and also some implemented solution so I will view it.

## image

[image]

Comment: You should definetly use a `Pipe`, using a form as input, and "Piping" your users array in your filter with the search field value as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I write a code for search pipe

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: "search"
})

export class SearchPipe {

    transform(value, term) {
        console.log(term + ' ' + value);
        if (term == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.filter((item) => item.Email.includes(term));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple pipe like below example

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 
transform(value: any, input: string) {
  if (input) {
   input = input.toLowerCase();
   return value.filter(function (el: any) {
    return el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1 || 
     el.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
   })
  }
  return value;
 }
}
```

You can update the pipe according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = [];
res = Object.assign([], this.data).filter(
  item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1,
)
```

where this.data is array of your data.

Answer (score 0):

At times you may have a table with many columns and you need to search all the data in the table irregardless of the column , so instead of having multiple pipes you can use below solution

Below is the get method that gets the data from server, we store a copy of the data in **this.itemsData** to help revert back to original table data when user clears the search box, the data is however put in table using **this.items**

```
    getItems() {
this.getItemSub = this.crudService.getBill(this.storedLocalData.sessionId)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.items = data;
    this.itemsData= this.items;

  })}
```

the filter method

```
filterBillsItems(event) {
const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
//search in all columns 
var columns = Object.keys(this.itemsData[0]);

if(!columns.length)
  return;

  const rows = this.itemsData.filter(function(d) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= columns.length; i++) {
      var column = columns[i];
      // console.log(d[column]);
      if(d[column] && d[column].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1) 
    {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });  

  this.items= rows;  }
```

in your html you have

```
<input
 placeholder="Type to filter all columns" 
 value=""
 (keyup)='filterBillsItems($event)'>
```

sample table in this case using the amazing [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable)  to draw the table , will also work in any way used to create the table

```
<ngx-datatable
                class="material ml-0 mr-0 expandable striped"

                [rows]="items"
                [columnMode]="'flex'"
                [headerHeight]="50"
                [footerHeight]="50"
                [limit]="30"
                [rowHeight]="'auto'"> 

                <ngx-datatable-column prop='clientName' name="Name" [flexGrow]="1" >
                  <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{ row?.clientName }}
                  </ng-template>
                </ngx-datatable-column>
                <ngx-datatable-column prop='clientLocation' name="Location" [flexGrow]="1" >
                  <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{ row?.clientLocation }}
                  </ng-template>
                </ngx-datatable-column>

              </ngx-datatable>
```